# Can Xcode ask / react to file changes outside of the IDE?

Tags: xcode

Is there are means whereby if files are altered outside of Xcode, that a warning in can be shown to ask if you want to refresh the file? This feature is available in Visual Studio, for example.

As a temporary solution, were working on source files in a Dropbox folder.
Although growl notifies us that some files has changed, Xcode doesn't know about these changes.

Comment: Strange, Xcode should pick up the changes without any problem. I often modify files outside of Xcode and it will reopen the file when I switch back to it.

Comment: Xcode updates the file without any warning.. I just tried with Xcode 4.3.1

Comment: Are you files under some sort of xcode-supported version control? I could have sworn that if you update file outside of xcode and the project is under subversion/git version control it would add an indicator to the file "M"??? I could be wrong. I know xcode wont automatically add the file, but it should tell you if a file was modified.

Comment: No we're not using source control. And if were not viewing the files in the ide, they do update. But not if we are viewing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Xcode won't do that, and since there's no support for plugins you're pretty much stuck with that behavior. Some suggestions:

- Create a local git repository (Xcode can do this for you when you create the project, I don't know if you can do it once it is created.
- Use another IDE, like AppCode (this isn't even a solution, just came to me and I decided to add it).

With a version control system you can see the little 'M' on edited files, browse changes, etc. But since you wrote that this is a temporary solution I bet you already know this.

Comment: I would love to use source control. However, there are a few of us working on a simple app in our own time. We've looked at the options, github, setting up a svn server. But we don't want to have a financial element at this stage.

Comment: Why didn't you go for github?